# I have a table 'posts' which contains a foreign key 'user_id, how can i add that key to table on migration?

Tags: mysql, migration, database-migration, laravel-7

this is the migration

```
 Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
```

i have tried to do it with this lines

```
$table->bigInteger(‘user_id’)->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
$table->foreign(‘user_id’)->references(‘id’)->on(‘users’)->onDelete(‘cascade’);
```

what i did

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer(‘user_id’)->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
            $table->foreign(‘user_id’)->references(‘id’)->on(‘users’)-
            >onDelete(‘cascade’);
```

**what i get**
ErrorExceptionenter

Use of undefined constant ‘user_id’ - assumed '‘user_id’' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Please recheck quotation used. Maybe you used the wrong character. They should be either " or ' (like you have with `'posts'`) but not ` (backtick) nor special like you have:
`$table->integer(‘user_id’)` <-- this quotation around user_id are chars: e28098 and e28099 a non-ascii chars. So, please first check that.

Comment: Check this similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9898304/2873481

Answer (score 0):

@Mirage Three questions:

1. why are you using backticks instead of single quotes?
2. why are you using just `$table->id();` when it should be `$table->integer('id');`?
3. why are you using `$table->timestamps();` when it should be `$table->timestamp('created');`?

This migration with tweaks to be single quotes instead of backticks, correctly using `$table->id();` and `$table->timestamp('created');` works just fine for me:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Posts extends Migration
{
     public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('posts')) {
            Schema::connection('migrate')->create('testPosts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->default(null);
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->timestamp('created');
            });
        }
    }

    public function down()
    {
        if(Schema::hasTable('posts')) {
            Schema::connection('migrate')->dropIfExists('posts');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using backticks instead of single quotes? 
answer : i got it like that from the source, but u have right.

answer to the 2end question: it's from laravel users migration template, or thats different case !

3rd question : good point ,,, im learning, its my first project (but it looks like when its $table->timestamp(); it automatically creates ( created_at updated_at)

Comment: it created the table but i still get this


  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: there might have been a problem when you tried to create the table in the first place where the foreign key was partially created. i'd refer to this doc to drop the foreign key constraint, then drop the table all together, then try to re run your migration. let me know what happens when you do that.

Comment: that key workd somehow, i tried to add a nother foreign key the same way , but it throws errors ..., losing my mind